# Remove MEDIA_URL prefix from serialized model

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

i have a django-restframwork project where i have set **MEDIA_URL** in *settings.py* file. the problen is when serialize a model i get the file name with **media** prefixed.

Here the response i am getting

```
{
"employees": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "neki",
        "doc": "/media/simple-nature-wallpapers-free-download-for-desktop-45.jpg"
    }
  ]
}
```

But i want the response without *media* prefixed like this

```
{
"employees": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "neki",
        "doc": "simple-nature-wallpapers-free-download-for-desktop-45.jpg"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have two solutions. Both of them have some problems

1. I can remove **MEDIA_URL** from *setting.py* file (Problem is i cant access the file from storage)
2. Or i can save the file name as `models.CharField()`. (Problem is i cant save file from ModelSerializer automatically)

So my  **Question** is how to solve these problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the **`to_represenataion()`** method of serializer

```
class YourSerializer(.....):
    # your code
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        rep = super(YourSerializer,self).to_representation(instance)
        try:
            rep['doc'] = rep['doc'].split('/')[-1]
        except KeyError:
            return rep
        return rep
```

Comment: You are right. But dont you think this is some kind of hack. i was expecting some standard way of doing  like with the help  django's inbuilt feature.

Comment: unfortunately, Django doesn't provide this functionality out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

If you sahre your serializer and views, i can help you better. but the short answer is:
if you send this response with post method , you can override create method in your views(if you are using generics.CreateAPIView). if get, override retrive and ... .
and then change your response as you want. you access to your response data there.

share your view and serializer for more cleare answer.

Comment: I dont want to do it by overidding a function. There is no problem in plain django